# Calculate the spherical intersection location

Tags: analytic-geometry

Having the values (x1 y1 z1), Based on the figure below, I need to find the (x2 y2 z2)

O1 ={0 0 0}
r1 = R1

O2 = {0 0 L}
r2 = R2

[image]

Comment: You could start by considering an easier, 2D case. The $z$-direction is not taken into consideration. From the equation of the line, you know that
$$
\frac{x_2}{y_2} = \frac{x_1}{y_2}
$$
And then, from the definition of the sphere (with radius $r_2$), 
$$
x_2^2 + (y_2 - r_2)^2 = r^2
$$
From the two equations you can solve $x_2$ and $y_2$. Then expand the logic to three dimensions.

Comment: @MattiP. thanks, but i don't understand second equation. would you please elaborate more?

Comment: It's the equation of the circle. What is the difficulty you're facing?

Comment: @alex What do you really want? The intersections between the two spheres and the line (light blue)? For any line passing by the origin?

Comment: @Cesareo , yes ,(x1,y1,z1) is intersection between big sphere  and blue line that i know the values , and looking for (x2,y2,z2) coordinate that is the intersection between  small sphere and blue line

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$
C_1\to ||P-O_1|| = R_1\\
C_2\to ||P-O_2|| = R_2\\
P_1 = (x_1,y_1,z_1) \in C_1
$$

with

$$
P = (x,y,z)\\
O_1 = (0,0,0)\\
O_2 = (0,0,L)
$$

how to obtain $P_2 = (x_2,y_2,z_2) \in C_2$ such that $O_1, P_1$ and $P_2$ are aligned ?

Choosing the line

$$
L\to P = \lambda \vec v
$$

with $ \vec v = P_1/R_1$ it's intersections with $C_2$ are obtained by solving for $\lambda$

$$
||\lambda\vec v-O_2|| = R_2
$$

or squaring

$$
\lambda^2||\vec v||^2-2\lambda <\vec v, O_2 > + ||O_2||^2 = R_2^2
$$

or

$$
\lambda = \frac{< \vec v, O_2 > \pm\sqrt{ < \vec v, O_2 > ^2-||O_2||^2+R_2^2}}{||\vec v||}
$$

but here $\vec v = P_1/R_1$ is an unit vector so

$$
\lambda = \frac{1}{R_1} < P_1, O_2 >\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{R_1^2}< P_1,O_2>^2-||O_2||^2+R_2^2}
$$

or

$$
\lambda = \frac{z_1 L}{R_1}\pm \sqrt{\frac{z_1^2 L^2}{R_1^2}-L^2+R_2^2}
$$

and thus we can have solutions for $P_2$ as

$$
P_2 = \left(\frac{z_1 L}{R_1}\pm \sqrt{\frac{z_1^2 L^2}{R_1^2}-L^2+R_2^2}\right)\frac{P_1}{R_1}
$$

NOTE

Here $< \cdot, \cdot > $ represents the scalar product of two vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_2 = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$ be the intersection of the given ray with the sphere centered at $O_2.$
Construct a triangle $\triangle O_1 O_2 P_2.$
Let angle $\theta = \angle O_2 O_1 P_2$; this is the angle between the ray and the positive $z$ axis.

Consider the triangle formed by the points $O_1 = (0,0,0),$
$(x_1,y_1,z_1),$ and $(0,0,z_1).$
This is a right triangle with the same angle $\theta$ at $O_1.$
From this right triangle, by examining the ratio of the hypotenuse to the
leg along the $z$ axis we find that
$\cos\theta = z_1/R_1.$

Applying the cosine law to triangle $\triangle O_1 O_2 P_2,$
we have
$$  R_2^2 = L^2 + r^2 - 2\cos\theta Lr. $$

Substitute $z_1/R_1$ for $\cos\theta$ and rearrange the terms to make this a quadratic equation over $r$:
$$ r^2 - 2\frac{z_1}{R_1} Lr + L^2 - R_2^2 = 0. $$

This can be solved by the usual formula for roots of quadratic equations:
\begin{align}
r &= \frac12 \left(2\frac{z_1}{R_1} L 
      \pm \sqrt{\left(2\frac{z_1}{R_1} L\right)^2 - 4(L^2 - R_2^2)}\right)\\
&= \frac{z_1}{R_1} L 
      \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{z_1}{R_1} L\right)^2 - L^2 + R_2^2}.
\end{align}

Now we want a point at distance $r$ from the origin in the same direction as
$(x_1,y_1,z_1).$
That is, we want a point $r/R_1$ times as far from the origin as $(x_1,y_1,z_1).$
Based on the diagram, we want to take the positive value of the $\pm$ part in the formula above;
the negative value will give us a "backward" projection to the point where
the line from $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ to $O_1$ intersects the smaller sphere on the other side of $O_1.$

So the final result is $(kx_1,ky_1,kz_1),$
where 
$$k = \frac1{R_1} \left(\frac{z_1}{R_1} L 
        + \sqrt{\left(\frac{z_1}{R_1} L\right)^2 - L^2 + R_2^2}\right). $$